# Check if User is in Many2Many field

Tags: django, m2m

I have the following model with a m2m field where logged in Users can show interest in a publication:

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Publication:
  title = models.CharField(max_lenth=512)
  users_interested = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views import View
from .models import Publication

class listPublicationView(View):
  def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

    publications = Publication.objects.all()

    return render(request, "base.html", {'publications': publications})
```

Now i try to produce a "i am already interested" in the template when a logged in user is already interested in the publication:

**base.html**

```
{% for publication in publications %}

  {{publication.title}}

  {% if currently logged in User is interested in publication (check users_interested) %}
      i am already interested
  {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

I think about something like this:

```
{% if user.id in publication.users_interested__id %}
```

Comment: You have to load the information you want in your view. The template isn't there to produce anything (but html, ofc). In your case, probably some form of `prefetch_related()` or `annotate()`.

Comment: Have you considered looking at/using template tags? They usually help me get the work done quickly. Look here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/custom-template-tags/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to look like a good solution:

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Publication:
  title = models.CharField(max_lenth=512)

  #added a reverse accessor
  users_interested = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='users_interested')
```

**view.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views import View
from .models import Publication

class listPublicationView(View):
  def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

    publications = Publication.objects.all()

    # create a set of group IDs that this user is a part of
    current_user = request.user
    user_publication_set = set(current_user.users_interested.values_list('id', flat=True))

    #pass set to template
    return render(request, "base.html", {'publications': publications, 'user_publication_set': user_publication_set})
```

**base.html**

```
{% for publication in publications %}

  {{publication.title}}

  {% if publication.id in user_publication_set %}
      i am already interested
  {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

Found this solution in [Django: check for value in ManyToMany field in template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8442010/django-check-for-value-in-manytomany-field-in-template?rq=1)

Comment: It is a much better solution indeed. The point is to always have the view determine what data should be loaded, so it can control the logic. That's exactly what you did.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```
{% if request.user in publication.users_interested.all %}
```

- `request.user` property holds the current logged in user
- Then you use the `in` operator with `publications.users_interested.all()` (Note that there are no parenthesis on `.all()` in template

Comment: And with this in the loop in his template, if he has, say, 1000 publications, his page suddenly crushes the database with 1001 queries.

Comment: this works -- but i will really have a few hundred publications